# How can we select string between two single quotes by escaping apostrophe using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Example Text: `'builder's margin' means the percentage stated in Item 8 of Schedule 1;`

Here I have a regex that selects words between two single quotes `/'(.*?[^\\])'/g`. But it's not working when i try to extract `builder's margin` from the example text because there is apostrophe
so it's only selecting up to `builder`. so is there any way that we can escape apostrophe and select up to margin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to support escape sequences (i.e. if your string is not a string literal presented as plain text), you can use

```js
(?!\b'\b)'([^']*(?:\b'\b[^']*)*)(?!\b'\b)'
```

Else, if the text you have can contain escape sequences, you can use

```js
(?!\b'\b)'([^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*)(?!\b'\b)'
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/VuK76w/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/VuK76w/1).

**NOTE**: replace `.` with `[^]` to match any chars including line break chars.

*Details*

- `(?!\b'\b)'` - the `'` char that is not enclosed with word chars on both ends
- `([^']*(?:\b'\b[^']*)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than `'`
  - `(?:\b'\b[^']*)*` - zero or more occurrences of a `'` not enclosed with word chars and then zero or more chars other than `'`
- `([^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*)` - Group 1 (in the second pattern):

  - `[^'\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
  - `(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of a `\` + any one char or a `'` that is enclosed with word chars and then zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
- `(?!\b'\b)'` - the `'` char that is not enclosed with word chars on both ends

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
'(.+?)'\B
```

which basically means `'`, then some content, then `'`, followed by a non-word char.

```js
a = `normal 'quoted' string`
b = `'builder's margin' means the percentage`
c = `this 'we'll handle'`


re = /'(.+?)'\B/

console.log(a.match(re)[1])
console.log(b.match(re)[1])
console.log(c.match(re)[1])
```

Note that this doesn't handle trailing apostrophes as in `'builders' margins' are...`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the middle apostrophe has no word character right after it, you can try this regex:

```sh
'(?:\\.|'(?=\w)|[^'])*'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HLE6OZ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `'`: Start opening `'`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\\.`: Match `\` and an escaped character
  - `|`: OR
  - `'(?=\w)`: Match `'` if it has a word character next to it
  - `|`:  OR
  - `[^']`: Match any character that is not `'`
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `'`: Closing `'`